# Mongoose: Using objectModel.schema doesn't work for parameter in other schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model, schema

With mongoose, if you define two Schemas:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const objectAModel = require("/pathTo/objectAModel");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const objectBSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  objectAArray: [objectAModel.Schema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("objectB", objectBSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const objectBModel = require("/pathTo/objectBModel");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const objectASchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  objectBArray: [objectBModel.Schema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("objectB", objectBSchema);
```

The first code works fine, but the second one throws an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `ObjectBArray`
```

So, I can't identify the problem, since both of the code snippets are the same, and if I delete the .schema from the objectBArray in the second snippet, everythin works. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have circular dependencies. The way to solve it would be to create a reference from one model to the other as follows:

```
// the schema in objectB.js
const objectBSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  objectAArray: [{
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "objectA"
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("objectB", objectBSchema);
```

```
// the schema in objectA.js
const objectASchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  objectBArray: [{
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "objectB"
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("objectA", objectASchema);
```

Note that now you don't need to import the models in to other model files at all. Also the `ref` name must match exactly to what you name your model in `mongoose.model`. Lastly you would be storing the `_id` of the related models in this array, and you can use `.populate` to fetch the related documents when running a find query